# Column 'ACCOUNT.ACCOUNT_ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to get available balance on last(max) date. I am trying to write below query but it is showing error.

```
select ACCOUNT_ID,AVAIL_BALANCE,OPEN_DATE,MAX(LAST_ACTIVITY_DATE) 
from ACCOUNT 
group by CUST_ID;
```

> Column 'ACCOUNT.ACCOUNT_ID' is invalid in the select list because it
>   is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY
>   clause.

I am new to sql. Can anyone let me know where I am wrong in this query?

Comment: The error description is pretty clear. What `ACCOUNT_ID` could the computer display when you group by *customer*? A customer may be associated with 100 accounts, which of those IDs would you display?

Comment: In any case this query asks for the latest (maximum) date by customer. It *doesn't* ask for the balance on the latest date.

Answer (score 0):

Any column not having a calculation/function on it must be in the `GROUP BY` clause.

```
select ACCOUNT_ID,AVAIL_BALANCE,OPEN_DATE,MAX(LAST_ACTIVITY_DATE) 
from ACCOUNT 
group by ACCOUNT_ID,AVAIL_BALANCE,OPEN_DATE;
```

Comment: But this query return all account detail from account table. I required only last activity date for last available balace

Comment: Right, so remove the columns you don't need, and adjust your `GROUP BY` accordingly

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting the most recent row for each customer, think `ROW_NUMBER()`, not `GROUP BY`:

```
;With Numbered as (
    select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
             PARTITION BY CUST_ID
             ORDER BY LAST_ACTIVITY_DATE desc) rn
    from Account
)
select ACCOUNT_ID,AVAIL_BALANCE,OPEN_DATE,LAST_ACTIVITY_DATE 
from Numbered 
where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to select one records having `max(LAST_ACTIVITY_DATE)` for each `CUST_ID`.

For this you can use `TOP 1 WITH TIES` like following.

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES account_id, 
                       avail_balance, 
                       open_date, 
                       last_activity_date 
FROM   account 
ORDER  BY Row_number() 
            OVER ( 
              partition BY cust_id
              ORDER BY last_activity_date DESC)
```

Issue with your query is, you can't select non aggregated column in select if you don't specify those columns in **group by**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the max activity date for a customer then your query should be as below

```
select CUST_ID, MAX(LAST_ACTIVITY_DATE) 
from ACCOUNT 
group by CUST_ID;
```

You can't select any other column which is not in the group by clause. The error message also giving the same message.

Answer (score 0):

```
with query(CUST_ID, LAST_ACTIVITY_DATE) as
(
    select 
        CUST_ID,
        MAX(LAST_ACTIVITY_DATE) as LAST_ACTIVITY_DATE
    from ACCOUNT 
    group by CUST_ID
)
select  
    a.ACCOUNT_ID,
    a.AVAIL_BALANCE,
    a.OPEN_DATE,
    a.LAST_ACTIVITY_DATE
from ACCOUNT as a
    inner join query as q
        on a.CUST_ID = q.CUST_ID
            and a.LAST_ACTIVITY_DATE = q.LAST_ACTIVITY_DATE
```